# Bash array in perl script

Tags: perl, bash, ini

I have a bash script which contains the only content (an array ) e.g

#### bash_arrray.sh

```
locDbList=(default default_test)
```

I need to use this array in a Perl script.

Is it possible to load the array definition from bash file into Perl in some way?

If not then how I can define a Perl file with the same array and load that in a second Perl script?

In second case :

#### perl_arrray.pl

```
second_perl_file.sh ( load the perl_array in here ).
```

The last option is to put the array information in a format which I can read from both Perl and bash, e.g an ini file

Comment: I have a feeling you've got an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).  Why do you want two Perl scripts?  What are you really trying to do?  Why can't you code everything in one Perl script? One Bash script?

Comment: I have a bash script that builds a package and puts the user param in a bash into file (in the form of array) .Later on during package installation ( perl based).I want to use those values in perl , thanks

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what do you suggest how to store config data which is accessible easly from both perl and bash , thanks

Comment: @sakhunzai, can you show some example content of the bash file?

Comment: @dan1111 bash has an array simply:  `locDbList=(default default_test)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't see it from `%ENV` and event if you run `declare -a` in perl, it still won't pull the arrays defined in the immediate outer scope.

You might have to work both ends for this. And it's not that easy, but here's a start.

#### Passing to Perl

- First, I created a bash function to ready this value to be passed.

  ```
  function pass_array
  {
      # get the array name 
      declare array_name=$1;
      # get all declarations for defined arrays.
      # capture the line that corresponds with the array name
      declare declaration=$(declare -a | grep --perl-regex --ignore-case "\\b$array_name\\b");
      # - At this point this should look like:
      #   declare -a* array_name='([0]="value1", [1]="value2", [2]="value3")'
      # - Next, we strip away everything until the '=', leaving:
      #   '([0]="value1", [1]="value2", [2]="value3")'
      echo ${declaration#*=}; 
  }
  ```
- You could pass it to perl like so:

  ```
  perl -Mstrict -Mwarnings -M5.014 -MData::Dumper -e 'say Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \@ARGV ], [ q[*ARGV] ] )' "$(pass_array locDbList)"
  ```
- On the Perl side, you might have a convenience function like this:

  ```
  sub array_from_bash {
      return shift =~ m/\[\d+\]="([^"]*)"/g;
  }
  ```

#### Named Array

Of course, you could want to retain the name of the array, to allow passing more than one, or locating it dynamically, say with other environment variables. (`export DB_LIST_NAME=locDBList`)

In that case, you might want to change what the `pass_array` bash function echoes.

```
 echo echo ${declaration#*-a[b-z]* };
```

And might want to have a Perl function like this:

```
sub named_array_from_bash {
    return unless my $array_name = ( shift // $_ );
    my $arr_ref = [ @_ ? @_ : @ARGV ];
    return unless @$arr_ref 
               or my ( $array_decl ) = 
                    grep { index( $_, "$array_name='(" ) == 0 } @$arr_ref
                    ;
    return array_from_bash( substr( $array_decl, length( $array_name ) + 1 ));
}
```

#### Environment Variable

Yet, another idea is simply export a variable with the same information:

```
declare decl=$(declare -a | grep --perl-regex --ignore-case "\\b$array_name\\b");
export PERL_FROM_BASH_LIST1=${decl#*-a[a-z]* };
```

And read that from Perl.

```
my @array = array_from_bash( $ENV{PERL_FROM_BASH_LIST1} );
```